# Need clarification on how callbacks work in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have hard time understanding how this callback is called:

```
$(function () {
        function getData(callback) {
            var now = Date.now();
            var hour = 60 * 60 * 1000;
            var temperatures = [];
            for (var k = 24; k > 0; --k) {
                temperatures.push([now - k * hour,
                    Math.random() * 2 + 10 * Math.pow((k - 12) / 12, 2)
                ]);

                }
            callback ({data: temperatures });
        }

        getData(function (data) {
            $.plot("#chart", new Array(data));
        });
    });
```

I am well aware what is happening in the loop just need clarification with the callback. So, the callback is just a another function and in it we are creating a method? And assigning a tempretures array to it? This part really confuses me. If "data" in the callback is a method why I cant rename it to anything else? While I can rename to anything I want the "data" argument when I am calling getData function.

Can somebody provide a more understandable version of this callback and tempretures array relationship? Thanks.

Comment: Data in the callback is an argument. The callback function is anonymous.

Comment: The function in getData takes object and reffering to it with "data" variable. In callback you pass this object - {data: temperature} you are confusing the data method here with the data variable in getData function. The first is a method of the object, the second - a name to refer to that object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an object which has one property called `data` the value of which is an array (your temperature). This object is passed as the first parameter of callback.

```
getData(function (data) {
  $.plot("#chart", new Array(data));
});
```

Here the object is being passed in as an argument called `data`. As written, I don't think this will work since what you need to do is pass in the *array* to `new Array()` and not the object. So do this:

```
getData(function (data) {
  $.plot("#chart", new Array(data.data));
});
```

It's a bit easier to understand if you rename the object property:

```
callback ({temperatures: temperatures});

getData(function (data) {
  $.plot("#chart", new Array(data.temperatures));
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the code won't work.  As the code stands, the plot method is called with a single element object array.  It could be that it's a chart plotting method and can handle multiple lines of data.  But in this instance, just one line of data is necessary.

Comment: This was really helpful and it works in this way too. Thanks!

Comment: If this is Flot that the OP is using then the second argument is `data` which ["is an array of data series"](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format).

Comment: `A series can either be raw data or an object with properties. The raw data format is an array of points` The object as described is only required to have a `data` property which would house the raw data. It looks like it will work either way.  Both your code and the original code should work just fine.  The original code just creates the object, which isn't really necessary in this case, but it does make it easier to add properties in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A callback is a way to say, "When you're done with what you're doing, call this method."

JavaScript is single threaded, but it is asynchronous, so you may have some calls that finish before others.  In these cases your code runs out of order.  Callbacks are a way to ensure that a method calls another method when it's finished and actions finish as you expect.

In the case of your code, I'll annotate it as I go through:

```
$(function () {
    function getData(callback) { //callback is a parameter, in our case a function to     be called later

        var now = Date.now();
        var hour = 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var temperatures = [];
        for (var k = 24; k > 0; --k) {
            temperatures.push([now - k * hour,
                Math.random() * 2 + 10 * Math.pow((k - 12) / 12, 2)
            ]);

            }
        callback ({data: temperatures }); //once you've calculated temperature, call the callback method with an object that has a property called 'data' and a value that is an array.
    }

    getData(function (data) {
        $.plot("#chart", new Array(data));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, the callback is just a another function and in it we are creating
>   a method? And assigning a tempretures array to it?

Kinda, the callback is a function, but you're not creating a method.  You're calling a method and assigning the array to it.

> This part really confuses me. If "data" in the callback is a method
>   why I cant rename it to anything else?

Wrong..."data" is not a method, it's a single element object array.  And you can name it whatever you want, as long as you change the name in the callback method...for example:

```
getData(function (newData) {
        $.plot("#chart", new Array(newData));
    });
```

> While I can rename to anything I want the "data" argument when I am
>   calling getData function.

You care calling `getData` because the for loop is in that function.  You are passing the `callback` method as a parameter in that function to handle the data once it's calculated.